# Get MDM User Email Address Using c#

Tags: c#, mdm, activesync

I have pushed user email address using airwatch activeasync custom settings. and now it successfully pushed and checked in registry.

**registry path:** `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\Diagnostics\ConfigManager\ActiveSync`

now i want to get this emailAddress using c#, so after search i find a way this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dmwmibridgeprov/mdm-activesync-user-accounts01-01

how to use this way in c#. I am newbie in c#.

Comment: You need to use Microsoft Management to query the property settings in Windows.  Here is an example : https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2014/08/11/sample-c-code-for-using-the-latest-wmi-classes-to-manage-windows-storage/

Comment: ` ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\Root\\cimv2\\mdm\\dmmap");
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MDM_ActiveSync_User_Accounts01_01");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
            ManagementObjectCollection allAttributes = searcher.Get();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
`
but get `allAttributes` collection empty.

Comment: See following article.  I think the namespace is wrong.  If still doesn't work use regedit EDIT : FIND : dmmap to see if there may be more than one location in registry where table occurs : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/using-powershell-scripting-with-the-wmi-bridge-provider

Comment: @jdweng  EDIT : FIND : dmmap found null.
registry has following
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Provisioning\Diagnostics\ConfigManager\ActiveSync\Metadata2: ./Vendor/MSFT/ActiveSync/Accounts/150f3d9b-f036-47f6-9814-71ca31a385ef

Comment: You are getting a little bit out of my expertise.  I'm not sure if this is a credential issue or just suing the wrong path(s).  I thought you edited the registry and added the email address.